# On MAC OS X 10.8.x how can an AppStore application install a kernel extension?

Tags: macos, cocoa, mac-app-store, kernel-extension

**Description**
I am planning on developing a scientific sandboxed application that will need to install a kernel extension to function properly.

**Code-related question**
How can the app install the kext when it is purchased? I mean, how will it be deployed?  Is there some (cocoa) API to call? I have searched for this answer without any luck. Seems most app don't require kexts.

**General question**
Will I be able to put such application on the appStore?
I have doubts since installing a kernel extension would defeat the sandboxing purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cannot do this with an app that would be accepted in the Mac App Store. As per the Mac App Store review guidelines..
2.18: Apps that install kexts will be rejected

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please could you elaborate a little more (why would it be rejected) or quote a rule that this kind of app would violate. Thx.

Comment: Installing a kernel extension would violate the Sandbox. You would need to distribute that kind of app outside of the Mac App Store. Definitely, the installer and the kernel extension would need to be distributed outside the app store. It *might* be possible to still create a separately sandboxed Mac App Store app that *happens* to support your kernel extension, but not sure if that would be accepted...

Comment: from the guidelines:Apps that include undocumented or hidden features inconsistent with the description of the App will be rejected

Comment: also from the guidelines: 2.15: Apps must be self-contained, single application installation bundles, and cannot install code or resources in shared locations

Comment: finally, from the guidelines: 2.18: Apps that install kexts will be rejected

Comment: Thank you very much for this reply. I don't have access to the document you quote. So your comments are really helpful.

Comment: You can access it once you create a developer account.

Comment: I know, but since I am not a professional, it will probably take me 18 months to get the app ready. During that time, I would rather avoid paying $100/year for the subscription.

Comment: you can create a developer account without paying. You cannot submit an app until you paid...

Comment: I do have a developer account. It is required to download Xcode. But I can't access the documentation. I used the links on this page: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html

Comment: @IsaMeg: You can download Xcode from the Mac App Store without a developer account. You're correct, though, that the MAS Review Guidelines require a Mac Developer Program membership (which costs $99).

Comment: Hmm. Didn't realize the guidelines would be available only to paid accounts. But certainly they are all over the web if you google a bit.